# Can I interact with a UIView subview and have it positioned behind a fullscreen UICollectionView sibling view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uicollectionview, subview

I have a UIViewController that has a UICollectionView subview (clear background) that fills up the entire screen. I also have another subview (picture of a cloud) that has a gesture recognizer attached to it that I can move via touch.

Is it possible to have that cloud subview appear behind the collectionView, above the background view, and still touchable? So far I can only get it to work on top of the collectionView, otherwise I can't interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not do it unless your collectionView is subview of your cloudView , but if you do so your collectionView also move with that .

if your cloudSubView is behind CollectionView , than it will not recieve touch ,so how will it going to move .